# Include/require file from Flysystem

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flysystem

My PHP application dynamically generates some script files that are later run by using `require` or `include`.

I'm now in the process of migrating my production server to Amazon Web Services, to get scaling and load balancing. This means that the generated script files should no longer be stored in the local file system, but rather in an S3 bucket.

Therefore I would like to use Flysystem, so I don't have to think about whether the files are stored locally (development) or in an S3 bucket (production).

But how do I `require` or `include` a file from Flysystem? Do I have to get the file content and then `eval` it?

Comment: flysystem is not for that purpose, `Flysystem is a filesystem abstraction which allows you to easily swap out a local filesystem for a remote one` it was written to deal with static files such as txt files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to `include` or `require` a file directly from Flysystem. A workaround is to get the content of the file and `eval` it. Note that you must handle any leading `<?php` and trailing `?>` tags in the `eval`ed file.

Answer (score -1):

Local storage:

```
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local;

$adapter = new Local(__DIR__.'/path/to/root');
$localFilesystem = new Filesystem($adapter);
```

S3 Storage:

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter;
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;

$client = S3Client::factory([
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'your-key',
        'secret' => 'your-secret',
    ],
    'region' => 'your-region',
    'version' => 'latest|version',
]);

$adapter = new AwsS3Adapter($client, 'your-bucket-name', 'optional/path/prefix');
$s3Filesystem = new Filesystem($adapter);
```

Then, open your file with one, and write to the other:

```
$contents = $localFilesystem->read('path/to/file.txt');
$s3Filesystem->write('path/to/file.txt', $contents);
```

You shouldn't need to require, include, or eval anything! Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do need to `require`/`include`/`eval` the file, as it is a dynamically generated php file that I want to run.

Comment: I thought you just wanted to shift the files from your old server onto amazon? Well I guess you could just eval($content);

Comment: Sorry, no. I guess the whole pre-story can be a bit misleading.

Comment: Feel free to make an answer that the file content must be `eval`ed, so I can accept it :)